# How to re-use fancybox3 iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

When using fancybox3 we want to dynamically change the link of an iframe. So we change the `data-src` attribute which works fine the first time. However, when we change the link via jQuery and opening the fancybox again, it opens the old `data-src`. How can you reuse the fancy box or destroy and recreate the fancybox 
?

```
<a class="inre-product--book" data-fancybox="iframe"
                   data-src="http://somelink.com"
                   data-type="iframe">
                    Link
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try thi, Change `var url =` in below code with your href element.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    autoScale: false,
    // href : $('.fancybox').attr('id'), // don't need this
    type: 'iframe',
    padding: 0,
    closeClick: false,
    // other options
    beforeLoad: function () {
        var url = $(this.element).attr("id");
        this.href = url
    }
}); // fancybox
```

Comment: The before load is triggerd but url not set. Reduced it to :
        jQuery('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
            beforeLoad: function () {
                var url = 'http://google.com';
                console.log('Debug: ' + url);
                this.href = url;
            }
        })

Answer (score 0):

Simply set new source using jQuery `data` method:

`$('selector').data('src', 'new link')`